# How to get only the key names from a curl(php) that have certain value

Tags: php, arrays, curl, foreach, get

So what im trying to do is to get only the keynames that have the required as their tag.
Im doing a curl get on this url https://api.mercadolibre.com/categories/MLB1002/attributes
With this code:

```
    <?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.mercadolibre.com/categories/MLB1002/attributes',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'Authorization: Bearer APP_USR-868446844464533-040421-c41459517982417c3732856e7e872541-224564420'
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);

$array = json_decode(trim($response), TRUE);

foreach($array as $item) {
  echo nl2br($item['name'] . "\n");
}
```

The values I get from only parsing it on PostMan is:

```
{
        "id": "BRAND",
        "name": "Marca",
        "tags": {
            "catalog_required": true,
            "required": true
        },
        "hierarchy": "PARENT_PK",
        "relevance": 1,
        "value_type": "string",
        "value_max_length": 255,
        "values": [
            {
```

But is a big list with 2000+ lines

What im trying to do is to put a if inside my foreach to only get the "name" that have the tag "required=true"... Any way that I can do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check in foreach

```
foreach($array as $item) {
  if($item['tags']['required']){
     echo nl2br($item['name'] . "\n");
  }
}
```

Comment: If you don't want to emit Php notices for missing indexes.  You can use the more verbose:     `if(isset($item['tags']['required']) && $item['tags']['required'] === true)` condition.